# awk to divide fields based on match in file1

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to do the below steps

1. find matching fields `$1` strings between `file1` and `file2`
2. if the `$1` strings match then `$2 in file1` is divided by `$3 in file2` (that is x which is 3 signifigant figures rounded up)
3. x is multiplied by 100
4. each x is subtracted from 100 and that is the `%`

**file1**

```
USH2A 21
GIT1 357
PALB2 3
```

**file2**

```
GIT1 21 3096
USH2A 71 17718
PALB2 13 3954
```

**awk**

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next;}{if ($1 in a) print $1, $2/a[$3];else print;}' file2 file1 > test
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=search FNR=2) fatal: division by zero attempted

awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$1;next;}{if ($1 in a) print $1, $2/a[$3];else print;}' file1 file2 > test
awk: cmd. line:1: (FILENAME=search FNR=1) fatal: division by zero attempted
```

**example**

```
USH2A match is found so (21/17718)*100 = 0.11  and 100-0.11 = 99.99%
GIT1 match is found so (357/3096)*100 = 11.53 and 100-11.53 = 88.47%
PALB2 match is found so (3/3954) *100 =  0.07 and 100-0.7 = 99.93%
```

I am going line by line in the code and can see that I am already getting errors.  Thank you :).

Comment: You need to protect against `a[$3]` being zero or null (eg. if the $3 value from your 2nd file doesn't exist as a $1 value in your first file). Something like `print $1, (a[$3] ? $2/a[$3] : "NaN")` would do it. It's not clear why you're using `a[$3]` instead of just `$3` though.

Comment: your math for USH2A  is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk 'function ceil(v) {return int(v)==v?v:int(v+1)}
        NR==FNR{f1[$1]=$2; next} 
       $1 in f1{print $1, ceil(10000*(1-f1[$1]/$3))/100 "%"}' file1 file2

GIT1 88.47%
USH2A 99.89%
PALB2 99.93%
```

note that there is no round-up in `awk` so defined a `ceil` function for this task.

Comment: Thank you both very much :)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
NR==FNR { a[$1]=$3; next }
$1 in a {
    x = (a[$1] ? ($2*100)/a[$1] : 0)
    printf "%s match is found so (%d/%d) *100 =  %.2f and 100-%.2f = %.2f%%\n", $1, $2, a[$1], x, x, 100-x
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
USH2A match is found so (21/17718) *100 =  0.12 and 100-0.12 = 99.88%
GIT1 match is found so (357/3096) *100 =  11.53 and 100-11.53 = 88.47%
PALB2 match is found so (3/3954) *100 =  0.08 and 100-0.08 = 99.92%
```